# How to have multiple binary directories with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

In my team we create a library. We use `cmake` and multiple third-party-libraries. We use the `cmake` command `ExternalProject_Add` to download and build the third-party libraries (which is done at compile time).

The problem is that when we clear the build directory to make a fresh build of our library, the third-party libraries are downloaded again, which is annoying.

I am wondering whether there is a way to specify another build directory for the third-party libraries so that they will be kind of "cached" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to install your third-party libraries outside of the build directory, by changing the location of the install part, for example with option `INSTALL_DIR` of `ExternalProject_Add()`.

Comment: I have been looking the documentation for a while, but never noticed/have the idea to use that. I'll try that thanks !

Comment: @dooxe You're welcome, also consider/try specifying the install prefix to your external project with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for CMake, or `--prefix` for a configure script.

Comment: I've just tried, and it works pretty well. Thanks a lot !